# Can I set j query validation to invalid without an input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I want to know if/how I can set custom validation. I’m working on a section to add items in a form, the user is asked if they would like to add an item, if they select yes, a section is made visible with all the input fields (description, value..) but the “add item”/“cancel” are <a> tags in a div and I haven't found a way to validate these like the rest of the inputs, instead I'm trying to see if the add/cancel div is visible (as this means the user didn't save the item details- when they select an option then the div is no longer visible). I’m looking for something along the lines of

```
$('form').validate(
    if ($(#add-or-cancel-div).is(':visible'){
        //validation = false
    }
)
```

I tried

```
$.validator.addMethod('itemRequiresAddOrCancel', function (element) {
    if (element.is(':visible')) {
        return false;
    } else { 
        return true;
    }}, "please pick an option");

$('form').validate(
    $(#add-or-cancel-div).rules('add', 'itemRequiresAddOrCancel');
    }
)
```

Is this the best way to approach this or can it be done another way?

Comment: First off, when asking for help, give enough code for a working demo.  I see no HTML markup here.  Secondly, you can use a hidden `<input>` element as the placeholder for validation in these unique situations.

Comment: FYI - you cannot put a standalone conditional statement or the `.rules()` method inside of the `.validate()` method.  Only specified options as key:value pairs are allowed.  Refer to the documentation, and the example code in questions tagged with this plugin.